# Conditional selection on multiindex datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a multiindex dataframe with the level 3 index being a datetime series. This datetime series are basically random dates with no particular order (they are dates of when a building construction was completed). How do i perform conditional selection using this datetime index? e.g. >=2014-1-1

(My clumsy solution so far is to convert this level 3 index into a column, then performing conditional selection based on this column e.g. df['Date'].dt.year>2013)

Comment: Please post sample data.

Answer (score 2):

First, sort your index, with [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) (eventually just for your `level=3`, depending on how you have generated the data)

Then using [`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html)
`df.loc[pd.IndexSlice: [:, :, :, dt.datetime(2014,1,1):, :]`

Comment: thanks for the tip. wasn't aware of indexslice at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IndexSlice.html). I learned to use it from the end of [this](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro.html) post.

Comment: thanks for the tip. wasn't aware of indexslice at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(2)>'2014-01-01']
```